# JVM GC behaviour on heap dump and unnecessary heap usage

Tags: garbage-collection, jvm, heap-dump

We have problem tuning the memory management of JVM's. The very same application running on the k8s cluster, but one of the pods' jvm heap usage rises to ~95% and, when we try to get a heapdump on this vs, somehow gc runs and heap usage drops suddenly, leaving us with a tiny heap dump.

I think the old space has grown unnecessarily, and gc did not work to reclaim memory (for nearly 15 hours). Unfortunately we can't see what is occupying the space, because the heap dump is very small as gc is forced.

All 3 pods are having memory of 1500m and
here is the jvm heap usage percentage graph (3 pods, green being the problematic one):

[image: JVM Heap Usage]

Details:

```
openjdk 15.0.1 2020-10-20
OpenJDK Runtime Environment AdoptOpenJDK (build 15.0.1+9)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM AdoptOpenJDK (build 15.0.1+9, mixed mode, sharing)
```

JVM Parameters:

```
-XX:MaxRAMPercentage=75
-XX:InitialRAMPercentage=75
-server
-Xshare:off
-XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256m
-Dsun.net.inetaddr.ttl=60
-XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow
-XX:+ShowCodeDetailsInExceptionMessages
```

The questions are:

- Why a full gc is called when we try to get heap dump?
- What is the motivation behind the gc not reclaiming memory and causes the application run with the heap size between ~70% and ~95%, while jvm can use and perfectly work with only 10%?
- What can be done to force jvm to do gc more aggresively to avoid this situation? Or should it be done for production environment?

Comment: Why are you specifying such obsolete arguments like `-server`? And is there a reason for `-Xshare:off`? Besides that, do you experience any *real* problem? According to your description, your application runs just fine for 15 hours (and probably would even longer), it’s just that a graph is plotted at a different place than you would like.

Comment: There is no difference between other pods by response time, it works fine, but such behavior results in excessive resource allocation and usage in cloud environments. The graph is added to show sawtooth pattern and dramatic heap usage drop at heap dump taking.

Comment: You mean this ~400MB difference between the peeks would have been used for other purposes if the graph was printed lower? That contradicts the fact that this memory is already reserved for the JVM. In fact, the operating system is not even aware about this difference, as this is a number internal to the JVM.

Comment: Sure, I think it can be used, when I inspect a local java process with visualvm, otherwise given by the java opts, it first allocates low heap size, then it grows up to the Xmx value when needed. https://imgur.com/a/g0ikzhm  Correct me if i'm wrong please.

Comment: When you say, one instance uses up to “70% of the heap size” and the other uses “95% of the heap size”, which heap size are you referring to? The allocated heap or the configured maximum heap? And when you assume that one instance has allocated less than the other, did you verify that assumption?

Comment: Configured maximum

Comment: Just to sum it up, you have set `InitialRAMPercentage` and `MaxRAMPercentage` to the same value, so you *request* the JVM to allocate a fixed amount of memory, regardless of how much it will eventually use. Even the JVMs which use less have usage peeks up to 70%, so it is very unlikely that they use that value as a trigger to release memory to the operating system. I guess, the container itself also has an assigned fixed amount of memory and doesn’t run any other relevant process besides your JVM, so no-one is there to benefit, even if the JVM did release the memory, right?

Answer (score 0):

JVM heap dump procedure has 2 modes

- **live objects** - this mode executes Full GC along side with heap dump. This is default options.
- **all objects** - heap dump would include all object on heap both reachable and unreachable.

Heap dump mode is usually possible to choose via tool specific option.

**Answering your questions**

> Why a full gc is called when we try to get heap dump?

Answered above

> What is the motivation behind the gc not reclaiming memory and causes the application run with the heap size between ~70% and ~95%, while jvm can use and perfectly work with only 10%?

Reclaiming memory required CPU resources and impacts application latency. While JVM is operating withing memory limits it will mostly avoid expensive GC.

Recent development of containers is driving some changes in JVM GC department, but statement above is still relevant for default GC configuration.

> What can be done to force jvm to do gc more aggressively to avoid this situation? Or should it be done for production environment?

Original answers lack problem statement. But general advises are

- manage memory limits per container (JVM derive heap size from container limits unless they are overridden explicitly)
- forcing GC periodically is possible, though unlikely to be a solution to any problem
- G1GC has wide range of tuning options relevant for containers

Comment: @Holger you are right, but this JVM options were so archaic, so they me think of old version of Java

Comment: Yes, some of those options are strange, I [even asked about them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65823168/65824803?noredirect=1#comment116381146_65823168) but got no answer. But others, like `-XX:+ShowCodeDetailsInExceptionMessages` are very new.